# Same HTML Responce is appearing for all request in JMETER with Swagger API

Tags: api, unit-testing, jmeter, automated-tests, swagger

Jmeter Response data not coming properly

API Tool: Swagger
Type: Json
Jmeter Template used for out put: "View Results Tree"

Exat Response data is not getting in JMeter but In Soap UI Exat Response data is getting in JSON

Could any help me out to get the JSON for Exat "Response Data"

After running the scripts (Threads- 1, Ramp Up period - 1, Loop Count - 1 ), below are the observations I noted in View Results Tree:

The Result Tree view shows all as Checked(Green) - OK
The Sample result for all screens shows Error Count as 0 - OK
But in the response tab when I try to view the results by using 'Render Html' response data - the response data shows the same response for all the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the "HTTP Header Manager"config Element for the "HTTP Request":
[image: screensort]